# Display image as 'video'

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an image file (for example img.png) which is updated (overwritten) every 20-30ms using a java program.

Now, I want the client to be able to 'watch' the image as it changing (it will look like a video streaming).

I used Javascript to update the image every 20-30ms but it is not that efficient as it consumes a lot of processing power. I also tried to use Ajax and jQuery.

Any suggestions on how to improve the performance? Can I use a player like jwPlayer or Flow Player? Should I use something different and more efficient?

Thanks.

PS. I have already implemented it using JApplet but I would like to avoid that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update image by appending a random string at the end.

```
function update(){
    $('#image').attr('src', $('#image').attr('src')+'?'+Math.random());
}

    setTimeout("update()",150);
```

Comment: That is what I am doing. But it consumes a lot of processing power.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you just want a slideshow; there are super fast efficient slideshows in JavaScript, i'm lazy so here's the jQuery version:http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/slideshow  if you're having performance issues using this, it's not because of the slideshow

Comment: Can I use this and set update time to 30-40ms without any problem?

Comment: did you look at it? first code block: $(function() {
 $('.slideshow').slideshow({ timeout: 2000, speed: 300 });
});    speed: 300 is in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

You can update image using javascript timer (setTimeout) [eg url](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: That is what I am doing. But it consumes a lot of processing power. I am looking for something more efficient!

Comment: @salamis this will not took that much processing power. this event only fire in required interval.

Comment: But the problem is that the required interval is too low. For example 100-200 ms.. That is the problem.

Comment: @salamis Then you can create video by using libs such as ffmpeg < http://ffmpeg.org/ >. After creating video you can play it in 'any video' player. FFMPEG supports a wide variety of formats

Answer (score 0):

> ..it consumes a lot of processing power

Note that 'processing power' is not the same as 'bandwidth'.

To save bandwidth, it would make more sense to assemble the images into a video at the server side, and stream the video to the client.  Video compression formats generally save a lot of bytes over a series of images, because they can compress images taking into account similar parts of different frames.

Comment: Can you suggest me a java library to encode the frame into a video and live stream it without the usage of applets?

Comment: Flash can show streaming video (and is better set to do it than an applet).  As to the libraries, I have no experience.